# Why does "Settings.Save" needs admin permissions?

Tags: vb.net, windows, permissions

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and Windows 7. I'm saving windows position when user close a form, and the program breaks in exception because I didn't run it whit admin permissions.

This is my App.Config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="Test.My.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
    </startup>
    <userSettings>
        <Test.My.MySettings>
            <setting name="InitialLocation" serializeAs="String">
                <value/>
            </setting>
            <setting name="TelefonosConsultados" serializeAs="Xml">
                <value>
                    <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                        <string>0123456789</string>
                    </ArrayOfString>
                </value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Server" serializeAs="String">
                <value>localhost</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Port" serializeAs="String">
                <value>3306</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Database" serializeAs="String">
                <value>dwh</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="User" serializeAs="String">
                <value>root</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Password" serializeAs="String">
                <value>password</value>
            </setting>
        </Test.My.MySettings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you go to add `Settings` to your project via the Project Properties window, there is a `Scope` option. If you use the `Application` scope instead of the `User` scope, you're saving that setting for **all** users of the application on that particular computer. Only administrators should be able to dictate settings for all users, hence the exception. .Net will store that setting in a location to which only administrator accounts have access, and therefore will require elevation in order to complete the save (which your process never prompted for).

If you instead choose the `User` scope, you won't need elevation, and the setting will save without complaining. However, only that user will see the new setting.

Comment: I have my `Settings` as `User` scope

In my `App.config` file I have this:

`   <userSettings>
        <Test.My.MySettings>
            <setting name="Server" serializeAs="String">
                <value>localhost</value>
            </setting>

            </Test.My.MySettings>
    </userSettings>`

Comment: With user settings, there should also be a settings file in the user's APP_DATA folder for your app that stores the setting value. What you're seeing in App.Config is just the default if the user has not saved their own setting yet.

Comment: That is precisely my problem. When I run my compiled program from the `Debug` folder, I get an error saying that I have no rights, and when I run the program with administrative rights, it runs fine. Similarly, if I start debug my program inside the IDE, I get a message asking me to restart the IDE with administrative credentials. Is something strange.

Comment: Try actually deploying it. Visual Studio has to play some games with app.config while debugging.